# Python Mocking a request for a bearer token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to figure out how to mock my request for a bearer token in python.
I have a class:

```
class grab_apitokens(object):

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, first_api_url, second_api_user, second_api_password, second_api_url):
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.second_api_user = second_api_user
        self.second_api_password = second_api_password
        self.first_api_url = first_api_url
        self.second_api_url = second_api_url

    def logintofirstsite(self):  
        b64val = base64.b64encode(self.consumer_key.encode()).decode()
        headers = {"Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64val}
        data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'validity_period': '3600'}
        try:
            response = requests.post(self.first_api_url, headers=headers, data=data)
            decodedresponse = json.loads(response.content.decode())
            access_token = decodedresponse['access_token']
            return access_token
        except:
            return None
            
    def logintosecondsite(self):
        header = {"accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        logindata = {'grant_type': 'password',
                     'username': "" + self.second_api_user + "", 'password': "" + self.second_api_password + ""
                     }
        try:
            returnedfromsite = requests.post(self.second_api_url + '/api/V1/token', 
headers=header, data=logindata)
            return returnedfromsite.json()['access_token']
        except:
            return None
```

What I can't figure out is how to mock that requests call and what it would look like in Python.

My test currently looks like:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):



    def setUp(self) -> None:       # PROBLEM BEGINS HERE
        self.grab_apitokens = grab_apitokens(actual_key, actual_site1, actual_user, actual_pass, actual_2nd_site)

    @patch('grab_apitokens.requests.get')
    def test_login(self, mock_get):
        mock_get.return_value.ok = True
        response = self.grab_apitokens.logintosite()
        assert_is_not_none(response)
        # self.assertEqual(True, False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How would I mock the requests.post functionality?

Comment: Is creating the `grab_apitokens` object inside `test_login` and dropping setUp an option? This way you can call init with whatever arguments you need.

Comment: I'm not quite following but whatever we need we can do. I just put it there because it would prevent me from having to call it for each test individually.

Comment: If you need to mock it for each test specifically then I would declare it in each test. Also, if you need to set the same urls for all tests you don't need to mock init, just use the test urls when you create the object in setUp since init does not do any calls, it just sets some fields to static values

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page still. The goal here is to remove the need for those real values in the setup class. I need to check that the functions written for the class will work without having to make external API calls. Somehow I need to fake the data I'm inputting in setUp, while having the methods be none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a good mentor I figured out that my approach was all wrong. Here's what I ended up with for the unit test:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.grab_apitokens = grab_apitokens("complete","gibberish","it really doesnt","matter","what is","in","here")

    @patch('grab_apitokens.requests.posts')
    def test_login(self, mock_get):
        mock_json = {'token': 'foo'}
        mock_get.return_value = Mock(ok=True)
        mock_get.return_value.json.return_value = mock_json
        mock_get.return_value.content = b'{"token": "foo"}'
        response = self.grab_apitokens.logintofirstsite()
        assert_equal(response, "foo")



if __name__ == '__main_
```

To understand what this does, I needed to know that what we're really mocking isn't the method logintofirstsite(), we're mocking the response that requests.post is making in the method. With mock_get, we're inject requests.posts to always be: {'token': 'foo'} . So everything after

```
response = requests.post(self.first_api_url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

in logintofirstsite() is what I'm really testing. Which is:

```
            decodedresponse = json.loads(response.content.decode())
            access_token = decodedresponse['token']
            return access_token
```

The setup before the requests.post call doesn't matter one bit. Since with {'token': 'foo'} is what my requests.post call returns, the returned value after that bit of logic is 'foo', and so the assert_equal back in MyTestCase passes.